# Python unittest create mock class

Tags: python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

**The Case**:
I've a class `View` in my code that creates an instance during execution, which one I want to mock.
I'm passing implementation of `View` before running the code.

```
class View:
    def __init__(arg):
        self.arg = arg
        self.inner_class = self.InnerClass()
```

item to test:

```
view.inner_class.some_method.assert_called_once()
```

**The Problem**:
I can't properly create a `MockView` class to get correct `mock_view_instance` during execution.

I've tried 1:

- Returns real object (result of Mock call) without `assert_called_once` method.

```
mock_instance = Mock(wraps=View, spec=View, spec_set=True)
```

I've tried 2:

- `inner_class` not exists (no entering to `__init__` method).

```
mock_instance = Mock(spec=View, spec_set=True)
```

I've tried 3:

- Ok but `View` isnstance can be instantiated without `arg` - it's error prone.
- `arg` not exists at this moment, it will be defined dynamically during a test call itself.

```
mock_instance = Mock(spec=View(arg='foo'), spec_set=True)
```

I've tried 4:

- `TypeError: 'View' object is not callable`.

```
mock_instance = Mock(wraps=View(arg='foo'))
```

I've tried 5:

- TypeError: 'NonCallableMagicMock' object is not callable
  (No matter `instance=True/False`)

```
mock_instance = create_autospec(spec=View(arg='foo'))
```

My dirty solution:

```
# Real object with mock methods (wrapper)
wrapper_instance = Mock(wraps=View, spec_set=True)  

# Return mocked object as instance  
# (don't use "wrapper_instance" as spec, it will cause infinite recursion).
wrapper_instance.side_effect = Mock(spec=Mock(wraps=View))
```

P.S. I'm preferring not to use `patch` because it's very implicit.
My architecture allows to set any required object during configuration.

Comment: You never showed the actual unit being tested. I am assuming there is some function you are testing, please include it in the example code. It is not clear whether that function receives an existing instance of `View` as argument or if it creates one in its body. Also I am curious why on earth you consider `patch` to be "very implicit" and what that even means in this context. What is more explicit than saying _"give me a mock of the following object please"_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say we have the following `code.py`:

```py
class View:
    class InnerClass:
        def some_method(self) -> None:
            print(self.__class__.__name__, "instance says hi")

    def __init__(self, arg: str) -> None:
        self.arg = arg
        self.inner = self.InnerClass()


def f(view: View) -> int:
    view.inner.some_method()
    return 42


def g() -> str:
    view = View(arg="foo")
    view.inner.some_method()
    return view.arg + "bar"
```

Here is how you might properly unit test the functions `f` and `g`:

```py
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch

from . import code


class CodeTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_f(self) -> None:
        mock_some_method = MagicMock()
        mock_view = MagicMock(
            inner=MagicMock(some_method=mock_some_method)
        )

        output = code.f(mock_view)
        self.assertEqual(42, output)
        mock_some_method.assert_called_once_with()

    @patch.object(code, "View")
    def test_g(self, mock_view_cls: MagicMock) -> None:
        mock_arg = "xyz"
        mock_some_method = MagicMock()
        mock_view_cls.return_value = MagicMock(
            arg=mock_arg,
            inner=MagicMock(some_method=mock_some_method),
        )

        output = code.g()
        self.assertEqual(mock_arg + "bar", output)
        mock_view_cls.assert_called_once_with(arg="foo")
        mock_some_method.assert_called_once_with()
```

To test `f`, we need to give it an argument that behaves like a `View` instance **in the context of `f`**. So all we need to do is construct a mock object that has all the `View` attributes needed inside `f`. The function relies on the `inner` attribute of `View` and the presence of `some_method` on that `inner` object. We want to ensure that `f` actually calls that method. Note that what I did was more than necessary and done for readability only. We could have just written the test method like this:

```py
    def test_f(self) -> None:
        mock_view = MagicMock()
        output = code.f(mock_view)
        self.assertEqual(42, output)
        mock_view.inner.some_method.assert_called_once_with()
```

For testing `g` we need to mock the entire `View` class for the duration of the test since we don't want to rely on any implementation details of how it is instantiated. This is where `patch` shines. We ensure that instead of actually calling `View` the function calls a mock returning another mock that behaves like a `View` instance **in the context of `g`**. Same logic from then on.

In general this is the prudent approach to unit test. We mock out **everything** we wrote ourselves that is not part of the unit under testing. The test should be totally agnostic to any implementation details of other units.

It would be a different story, if `View` was a third-party or built-in class. In that case we would (usually) use it as is under the assumption that the maintainers of that class do their own testing and that it works as advertised.